# Base64 encoding in Java / Groovy

Tags: java, grails, encoding, groovy, base64

What is the proper way to convert a byte [] to a Base64 string in Java? Better yet would be Grails / Groovy because it tells me that the `encodeAsBase64()` function is deprecated. The `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` package isn't recommended for use and outputs a different size string on some Windows platforms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apache Commons has many utilities:

Binary Package: http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Download:
http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi

Answer (score 111):

The preferred way to do this in groovy is:

```
 def encoded = "Hello World".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
 assert encoded == "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ="
 def decoded = new String("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=".decodeBase64())
 assert decoded == "Hello World"
```

Comment: The issue with this is that `encodeBase64` puts line a line ending in every 76 characters which messes up the length of the string. I ended up using `def encoded = byteArray.collect { it as char }` instead of a Base64 encoding.

Comment: By default, groovy doesn't insert extra newlines in the encoding, since version 1.6.0.  Calling `encodeBase64(true)` enables that behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the open source [Base64Coder](http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/) library

```
import biz.source_code.base64Coder.Base64Coder

@Grab(group='biz.source_code', module='base64coder', version='2010-09-21')

String s1 = Base64Coder.encodeString("Hello world")
String s2 = Base64Coder.decodeString("SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=")
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own method like this :)

```
public class Coder {
private static final String base64code = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

public static String encodeAsBase64(String toEncode) {
    return encodeAsBase64(toEncode.getBytes())
}

public static String encodeAsBase64(byte[] toEncode) {
    int pos = 0;
    int onhand = 0;

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for(byte b in toEncode) {
        int read = b;
        int m;
        if(pos == 0) {
            m = (read >> 2) & 63;
            onhand = read & 3;
            pos = 1;
        } else if(pos == 1) {
            m = (onhand << 4) + ((read >> 4) & 15);
            onhand = read & 15;
            pos = 2;
        } else if(pos == 2) {
            m = ((read >> 6) & 3) + (onhand << 2);
            onhand = read & 63;
            buffer.append(base64code.charAt(m));
            m = onhand;
            onhand = 0;
            pos  = 0;
        }
        buffer.append(base64code.charAt(m));
    }
    while(pos > 0 && pos < 4) {
        pos++;
        if(onhand == -1) {
            buffer.append('=');
        } else {
            int m = pos == 2 ? onhand << 4 : (pos == 3 ? onhand << 2 : onhand);
            onhand = -1;
            buffer.append(base64code.charAt(m));
        }
    }
    return buffer.toString()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

(adding this to this thread in the hopes that somebody else will get a hit on this and doesn't have to waste his valuable time)

I got stymied today when I tried to add in my Grails 2.3.11/Groovy 2.1.9 application the output of

```java
String src = render(
        model:    ...,
        template: ...,
    )
    .encodeAsBase64()
```

as a `data-` attribute to a DOM element. But the `atob()` in the corresponding JavaScript, i.e. the code that decodes the Base64 string from the data attribute, kept complaining about illegal characters, while other decoders, e.g. `base64 -d` accepted the same Base64 string without problems.

The solution is to force the `render()` return value to a single string and then apply the Base64 encoding, i.e.

```java
String src = render(
        model:    ...,
        template: ...,
    )
    .toString()
    .encodeAsBase64()
```

or (if you consider `encodeAsBase64()` as deprecated):

```java
String src = render(
        model:    ...,
        template: ...,
    )
    .toString()
    .bytes
    .encodeBase64() // add 'true' for chunked output
```