# how to convert hexadecimal to base64 format in groovy script

Tags: groovy

I'm not able to convert hexadecimal value to base64 format using:

```
public static Writable encodeHex(Byte[] data)
```

Is there any sample code to convert into base64?

Comment: What do you mean by encode hexadecimal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4189017/6509

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--- *EDIT* ---

So for Groovy, apparently this is so simple :

> String encoded = s.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()

References :

- http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2009/11/groovy-goodness-base64-encoding.html
- http://prystash.blogspot.fr/2009/06/groovy-base64-encodedecode-with-and.html

--- *END EDIT* ---

Since Java 8, there are Encoder / Decoder included in the API for Base64.

See the javadoc (JSE 8) :

- [Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)
- [Base64.Encoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html)
- [Base64.Decoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html)

And this article : [Base64 Encoding in Java 8](http://java.dzone.com/articles/base64-encoding-java-8).

There's also a paragraph about that in [Java 8 Friday: Let’s Deprecate Those Legacy Libs](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/05/java-8-friday-lets-deprecate-those-legacy-libs.html).

But if unfortunately like 99% of the people you don't use Java 8 yet, there are another libs :

- [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/)
- [Guava's BaseEncoding](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html)

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the *Groovy* part !  :-(